# ASM code not injecting in the correct location

Tags: java, code-injection, bytecode

I am attempting to inject two lines of code into a class.  I managed to get it working once before, but I am having trouble getting it working again.  For some reason, no matter what I do, I cannot get the code to run at runtime, even though it supposedly injects successfully.  Here is my injection method:

```
 public byte[] patchBlockRotatedPillarASM(String name, byte[] bytes, boolean obfuscated)
 {
        String targetMethodName = "";
        if(obfuscated == true)
        {
            targetMethodName ="a";
            System.out.println("******** Using obfuscated method");
        }
        else
        {
            targetMethodName ="onBlockPlaced";
            System.out.println("******** Using unobfuscated method");
        }
        //set up ASM class manipulation stuff. Consult the ASM docs for details
        ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
        ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(bytes);
        classReader.accept(classNode, 0);
        //Now we loop over all of the methods declared inside the Block class until we get to the targetMethodName "onBlockPlaced" 
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Iterator<MethodNode> methods = classNode.methods.iterator();
        while(methods.hasNext())
        {
            MethodNode m = methods.next();
            System.out.println("********* Method Name: "+m.name + " Desc:" + m.desc);
            int fdiv_index = -1;
            //Check if this is onBlockPlaced and it's method signature is (Lnet/minecraft/world/World;IIIIFFFI)I
            if ((m.name.equals(targetMethodName) && m.desc.equals("(Lnet/minecraft/world/World;IIIIFFFI)I")))
            {
                System.out.println("********* Inside target method!");

                AbstractInsnNode currentNode = null;
                AbstractInsnNode targetNode = null;

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Iterator<AbstractInsnNode> iter = m.instructions.iterator();
                int index = -1;

                //Loop over the instruction set and find the instruction 21 which does the line before the ILOAD
                while (iter.hasNext())
                {
                    index++;
                    currentNode = iter.next();
                    System.out.println("********* index : " + index + " currentNode.getOpcode() = " + currentNode.getOpcode());
                    System.out.println(currentNode);

                    //Found it! save the index location of instruction ILOAD and the node for this instruction
                    if (currentNode.getOpcode() == 21)
                    {
                        targetNode = currentNode;
                        fdiv_index = index;

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("********* fdiv_index should be 2 -> " + fdiv_index);
                if (targetNode == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Did not find all necessary target nodes! ABANDON CLASS!");
                    return bytes;
                }
                if (fdiv_index == -1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Did not find all necessary target nodes! ABANDON CLASS!");
                    return bytes;
                }
                InsnList toInject = new InsnList();
                this.addPlaceEvent(toInject, m, targetNode);
                /*toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0));//ALOAD 0
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1));//ALOAD 1
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ILOAD, 2));//ILOAD 2
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ILOAD, 3));//ILOAD 3
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ILOAD, 4));//ILOAD 4
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ILOAD, 5));//ILOAD 5
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.FLOAD, 6));//FLOAD 6
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.FLOAD, 7));//FLOAD 7
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.FLOAD, 8));//FLOAD 8
                toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ILOAD, 9));//ILOAD 9
                toInject.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "net/minecraft/block/Block", "onBlockPlaced", "(Lnet/minecraft/world/World;IIIIFFFI)I"));//INVOKESPECIAL net/minecraft/block/Block.onBlockPlaced (Lnet/minecraft/world/World;IIIIFFFI)I

                m.instructions.insert(toInject);*/

                System.out.println("Patching Complete!");
                break;
            }
        }
        //ASM specific for cleaning up and returning the final bytes for JVM processing.
        ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        classNode.accept(writer);
        return writer.toByteArray();
  }
```

Here is the method that I am trying to inject into:

```
public int onBlockPlaced(World par1World, int par2, int par3, int par4, int par5, float par6, float par7, float par8, int par9)
{
    int j1 = par9 & 3;
    byte b0 = 0;

    switch (par5)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            b0 = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            b0 = 8;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
            b0 = 4;
    }

    return j1 | b0;
}
```

And here is the bytecode of the method above:

```
  // access flags 0x1
  public onBlockPlaced(Lnet/minecraft/world/World;IIIIFFFI)I
   L0
    LINENUMBER 33 L0
    ILOAD 9
    ICONST_3
    IAND
    ISTORE 10
   L1
    LINENUMBER 34 L1
    ICONST_0
    ISTORE 11
   L2
    LINENUMBER 36 L2
    ILOAD 5
    TABLESWITCH
      0: L3
      1: L3
      2: L4
      3: L4
      4: L5
      5: L5
      default: L6
   L3
    LINENUMBER 40 L3
   FRAME APPEND [I I]
    ICONST_0
    ISTORE 11
   L7
    LINENUMBER 41 L7
    GOTO L6
   L4
    LINENUMBER 44 L4
   FRAME SAME
    BIPUSH 8
    ISTORE 11
   L8
    LINENUMBER 45 L8
    GOTO L6
   L5
    LINENUMBER 48 L5
   FRAME SAME
    ICONST_4
    ISTORE 11
   L6
    LINENUMBER 51 L6
   FRAME SAME
    ILOAD 10
    ILOAD 11
    IOR
    IRETURN
   L9
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lnet/minecraft/block/BlockRotatedPillar; L0 L9 0
    LOCALVARIABLE par1World Lnet/minecraft/world/World; L0 L9 1
    LOCALVARIABLE par2 I L0 L9 2
    LOCALVARIABLE par3 I L0 L9 3
    LOCALVARIABLE par4 I L0 L9 4
    LOCALVARIABLE par5 I L0 L9 5
    LOCALVARIABLE par6 F L0 L9 6
    LOCALVARIABLE par7 F L0 L9 7
    LOCALVARIABLE par8 F L0 L9 8
    LOCALVARIABLE par9 I L0 L9 9
    LOCALVARIABLE j1 I L1 L9 10
    LOCALVARIABLE b0 B L2 L9 11
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 12
```

The instructions for the lines I need:

```
     public void addPlaceEvent(InsnList iList, MethodNode mNode, AbstractInsnNode tNode)
     {
         //LINENUMBER 87 L0 (possibly unneeded)
         iList.add(new TypeInsnNode(Opcodes.NEW, "timeTraveler/mechanics/BlockPlaceEvent"));//NEW timeTraveler/mechanics/BlockPlaceEvent
         iList.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.DUP));//DUP
         iList.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0));//ALOAD 0
         iList.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ILOAD, 2));//ILOAD 2
         iList.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ILOAD, 3));//ILOAD 3
         iList.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ILOAD, 4));//ILOAD 4
         iList.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "timeTraveler/mechanics/BlockPlaceEvent", "<init>", "(Lnet/minecraft/block/Block;III)V"));//INVOKESPECIAL timeTraveler/mechanics/BlockPlaceEvent.<init> (Lnet/minecraft/block/Block;III)V
         iList.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ASTORE, 5));//ASTORE 5
         //L1 (possibly unneeded)
         //LINENUMBER 88 L1 (possibly unneeded)
         iList.add(new FieldInsnNode(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "net/minecraftforge/common/MinecraftForge", "EVENT_BUS", "Lnet/minecraftforge/event/EventBus;"));//GETSTATIC net/minecraftforge/common/MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS : Lnet/minecraftforge/event/EventBus;
         iList.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 5));//ALOAD 5
         iList.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "net/minecraftforge/event/EventBus", "post", "(Lnet/minecraftforge/event/Event;)Z"));//INVOKEVIRTUAL net/minecraftforge/event/EventBus.post (Lnet/minecraftforge/event/Event;)Z
         mNode.instructions.insert(tNode, iList);
         //POP (possibly unneeded)
         //L2 (possibly unneeded)
     }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: From what I see in the code you have posted, you are iterating over all instructions and not stopping once you have found the instruction you are searching for. So you will use the *last* occurrence of ILOAD, not the first one. But it is not clear whether it has any impact as your actual code manipulation, i.e. the `addPlaceEvent` method, is not contained in your problem description. The only code we can see is commented out.

Comment: I have added the addPlaceEvent method.

Comment: What is the output of your System.out.println() lines?